# MVC 4 : ActionExecutingContext geting incorrect data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, actionmethod

I have Action Filters which gets executed before every action method.
In the first filter `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` the `filterContext` is having the wrong data. So I need to know from where the ActionExecutingContext object gets populated. I have looked into the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext(v=vs.118).aspx) link. but the one line explanation is not clear to me.

**EDIT 1:** code to redirect

```
return Redirect("/SUser/Content/Collection/" + ID);
```

before going to the `Content` Controllers `Collection` action method, following filters method get executed.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){}
```

the parameter `filterContext` should contain the URL `"/SUser/Content/Collection/"` but instead of that it contains a different URL and because of that it is getting redirected to the wrong action method.**I want know How and Where the `ActionExecutingContext` class object gets populated so that if allowed I will set the correct URL.**

Comment: please post what incorrect data you are getting..its impossible to guess from what you wrote...

Comment: @SamGhatak I am Redirecting to from one controller to other controlllers action method. before the control goes to the target controller action method filter method `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` gets executed. and the `URL` in `filterContext` object is not the one I am passing from the source controller.

Comment: Sorry, it would be best if you put the code of the filter here..

Comment: How are you accessing the URL in filterContext?

Comment: @SamGhatak Added code.